# How react-native does the same as html, multiple images are mixed in the same line?

Tags: react-native

html:[image]

1. But in react-native, this is my code, the margin doesn't work:

[image](Allow me to put a picture because I am not very skilled at operating this code editor)

My other attempt:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
       <Text>12444444444444442222222222222222222222222222222</Text>
       <Image source={{uri: url}} style={{width:20,height:20}} />
       <Text>1244444444444444222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</Text>
</View>
```

But it works very badly [image]

Comment: Remove `flexDirection: 'row'`

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this yellow image what you want to do?

> You can use it in view

```
<Text> Your text
       <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginLeft: 5,
          marginRight: 5
       }}>
            <Image source={{uri: url}} style={{width: 20, height: 20,}}/>
       </View>
       Your text
 </Text>
```

> without View use space in same line

`<Text>asdasdad` *{space}*`<Image source={{uri: url}} style={{width: 20, height: 20,}}/>`*{space}*`hasgdjhasd</Text>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, in code 1, the text component can't contain the view component, and [can't add a child that doesn't hava a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function]. The way to add space in code 2 is very clever, but when the length exceeds The width of the screen is automatically wrapped after the image.